# In which use-case do I need signing if decrypting a message is already a verification process?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, sign

I wrote a desktop application and I want to implement a simple license system with base64 serial keys. The server generates a JSON file, encrypts it via RSA, and it will be opened by my software. The JSON file just contains the email address and the client name.

1. Means, if I can decrypt the message with the public key, it must be a valid serial/license key, correct?
2. When do I need signing? Doesn't successfully decrypting a message not imply that the owner of the private key created the message?

Disclaimer: Cryptography is a new topic for me, so please be aware of the lack of basic knowledge on this topic.

Comment: RSA encryption is performed with the public key, decryption uses the private key. "Encrypting" with the private key **is** signing.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming! It can never be the other way around, correct? That I encrypt with private key and decrypt with public key?

Comment: Well, there are debates about terminology but I just think everything works better if we use the same terminology as follows: we have four basic operations in RSA: encryption, decryption, signing and verifying. Encryption uses the recipient's public key. Thus anybody can encrypt but only the recipient can decrypt with their private key. Signing use the signer's private key, and everyone can verify using the signer's public key.

Comment: Thank you very much! I could accept that as an answer!